# Detect the source of CheckChanged of a checkbox in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, checkbox

The `CheckedChanged` event of a `CheckBox` is fired when the page is loading up (on data binding), in addition to the user actually checking/unchecking.

Is there a way to detect whether `CheckedChanged` event was fired by a user action or otherwise?

In WinForms/WPF, I used to define a boolean variable like Loading = true; and then used to set Loading = false; once page load is finished. Then, the `CheckedChanged` event would check if Loading is false to execute the logic. Here's how I used to do it:

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Loading == true) return;

    //execute logic...
}
```

With async functions all over, I am unable to fit the Loading trick correctly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried setting Loading false in OnAppearing method of the page?

Comment: Yes, that's where I am setting it.

Answer (score 0):

> In WinForms/WPF, I used to define a boolean variable like Loading = true; and then used to set Loading = false; once page load is finished. Then, the CheckedChanged event would check if Loading is false to execute the logic. Here's how I used to do it:

I change bool userchecked value before and after setting BindingContext = new checkmodel(), to To detect whether the CheckBox_CheckedChanged first time trigger is user or data binding.

```
 public partial class Page18 : ContentPage
{
    private bool userchecked;   
    public Page18()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userchecked = false;          
        this.BindingContext = new checkmodel();
        userchecked = true; 
    }

    private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(userchecked==true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("user checked!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("don't user checked!");
        }
    }

  
}

public class checkmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _ischecked;
    public bool ischecked
    {
        get { return _ischecked; }
        set
        {
            _ischecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ischecked");
        }
    }
    public checkmodel()
    {
        ischecked = true;
    }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, to notify data update.

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```